# Visual studio 2019 unterminating background processes - high cpu use, lag

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

In the most recent version of VS 2019 now 16.3.8 but have had the same issue with other release (16.3.7, 16.3.6, 16.3.5) I am finding that after a number of hours of use I have a number of background processes (visible in the small icon at the bottom left of the screen) that never terminate.  It doesn't say much about them just "background processes" and the number of the them steadily increases until at anything above 5 VS becomes unusably slow with a high degree of lag on any operation, even typing (not very "background" then).

There are a few posts online of people describing the same problem but no solution presented has helped; eg I have found that if I delete the vs directory, the processes go away but sure enough they return a few hours later or sometimes quicker. Another suggestion was to delete all temp files but no improvement.  I have registered an issue with MS but who knows if they'll ever respond (why do we pay a licence fee??).  Has anyone else experienced this and know of any solution?

As its stands the issue became so annoying I have reverted back to 2017 which doesn't have the problem.

Icon at bottom left:
[image]

When I click this it says  "Running low priority background tasks" and a count which steadily increases.  No more information than that.

[image]

Ive left VS running for a long time and they never seem to finish.

I've disabled every extension I have installed but no difference

if anyone else experiencing then please upvote my support query with microsoft to get it up the priority list  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/782552/high-cpu-usage-16.html

Comment: It's not clear what you're seeing. It would be helpful if you included a screenshot or something. As for the background tasks, if you click on the icon it should show a list of what is currently running, and have a name... are you saying it doesn't show a name?

Comment: @Herohtar unfortunately I've not been using vs 2019 for a while so I don't immediately have the problem (using 2017).  Decided to post here as getting no answer from Microsoft.  I'm talking about the little icon at the bottom left.  It really doesn't saying anything more than "Running 7 background processes".  I know what you mean usually it says "performing code analysis" or something but with this it does not.  I've added a screen shot

Comment: Sadly (or thankfully) mine doesnt do this it has some on startup but they all finish. - could it be related to some plugins you have

Comment: @BugFinder it may be I'll try disabling things

Comment: The only message similar to what you're saying here that I see in my installation of 2019 is "Running low priority background tasks". Everything else shows as a specific task with a name, so I'm not sure what you're seeing. I haven't experienced any issues running 2019 extensively.

Comment: @Herohtar thats exactly the message.  I get that message and the number of tasks increases steadily until vs becomes unusable.  I note version 16.3.7 is now available which will be my first thing to try

Comment: updated q with screenshots, 16.3.7 no difference

Comment: anyone any suggestions of anything I could disable?  I've gone into Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> Installed and click the Disable button for every extension

Comment: I have seen this: Pressing Run or Build would often take  a long long time (up to 10 minutes), even for tiny applications. Aborting the Build and trying again one or more times did help. I gues VS was sitting on some build files itself which it then could not overwrite. I tried all things but never found the reason. Sometime later  (a few months) it was gone; no idea where it came from or where it went..

Comment: I have this exact problem. Updated to 16.3.7 and it made no difference. More than 100 tasks keep running all the time and CPU is between 50-60%. I have all the extentions disabled to no effect.

Comment: @HadiEskandari It may help if you upvote my MS support request: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/782552/high-cpu-usage-16.html  I'm hoping to collect a new trace for them to look at today.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a half solution to this from msdn.  However, its worth noting that the problem has resurfaced in a slightly different form.  The below may help some people however.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/672009/live-analysis-eats-up-memory-resulting-in-vs-crash.html?childToView=858720#comment-858720

which has the following post:

As a workaround, add a rulset with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="MyRules" Description="My Rules" ToolsVersion="16.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Features">
    <Rule Id="IDE0067" Action="None" />
    <Rule Id="IDE0068" Action="None" />
    <Rule Id="IDE0069" Action="None" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

You can add the ruleset to your project/solution as follows:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/using-rule-sets-to-group-code-analysis-rules?view=vs-2019#specify-a-rule-set-for-a-project

Answer (score 6):

I also had this issue, and was causing my builds to take way longer than it did in previous versions. The tasks seem to just never complete which then led me to believe it was a privilege issue. I suggest finding your **devenv.exe**

usually located at ***C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE***

Right click and open as administrator, then open your solution project.

this actually fixed my issue.

Comment: Same problem in VS 2022 - Same solution. Run VS as an Administrator